# Disable Password Authentication

Tags: apache, .htaccess

2 days ago I reset my VPS server at hostgator. Now when I go login into my wp-admin on my multisite I'm asked to authenticate user | password.

At one point 6-12 months ago I was using htaccess with htpasswd but had committed them out and no longer in use. I have now deleted those files.

So my question is how do I disable this or edit a file in the root directory? I do have VZ access and as a last resort can stumble with the command line.

This is effecting all sites on this server in the same manner.

I tried uncommitted PasswordAuthentication no - in the client ssh_config file and restarted the server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This has now been resolved. Apparently when Hostgator did a reboot a htaccess file got installed in the ./home dir

```
ErrorDocument 401 "Authorization Required"
<FilesMatch "wp-login.php">
    AuthName "Restricted"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /home/.wp-admin
    require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

There was a also a file installed called .wp-admin with a user / pw

```
hgprotect:xxxxx
```

After committing out everything works fine again.